# LocalStorage does not update when I submit details from edit form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using jQuery to develop a mobile app. The interesting thing is when I edit the details of an employee, in the listview the update is visible, but when I look in the localstorage the update does not reflect, also the page for full details of the employee does not update as well. However if I refresh the browser the updates show. How do I get both the localstorage and details page to update without refreshing the browser.

I am using two different forms, one to add a new employee, and another to edit employee details.

Thanks for any suggestions

Here are my codes for adding new employee

```
                       //user input to Add Employee Form
        $('#add_new_employee_form').on('submit', function(){



          var newEmployee = {
       id: employees.length+1,
       employeeno: $('#employeeno').val(),
       employeename:$('#employeename').val(),
       employeebirth:$('#employeebirth').val(),
       employeestate: $('#employeestate').val(),
       employeephone:$('#employeephone').val(),

     };
       employees.push(newEmployee);

       addEmployee(newEmployee);


   //save offline
    localStorage.setItem('employees', JSON.stringify(employees));

     //Alert when case saved successfull
       toast('Employee added successfully.'); 

    //refresh the list view
      $('#employee_list').listview("refresh");     

     //Change page to home
      $.mobile.changePage('#home_page');

       return true;

   });        


 //execute function to show cases
      showEmployees();
```

Here is my code for editing employee

```
                      // Editing Saved Cases

        //User input to Edit form function
     $('#edit_employee_form').on("submit", function(){

var x=document.forms["edit_employee_form"]["id"].value;  //here we are taking the value of employee id

      //and saves the new values to editEmployees
 var editEmployees = JSON.stringify({
    id: x,
     employeeno: document.forms["edit_employee_form"][" employeeno"].value,
    employeename:document.forms["edit_employee_form"]["employeename"].value,
   employeebirth:document.forms["edit_employee_form"]["employeebirth"].value,
   employeestate: document.forms["edit_employee_form"]["employeestate"].value,
    employeephone:document.forms["edit_employee_form"]["employeephone"].value,
    });
    var y=x-1;                      

    cases[y]=JSON.parse(editCases);   //here we updates the values

//After the selected case has been edited
localStorage.setItem("employees", JSON.stringify(employees));   //set the update values to localstorage
toast('Employee Updated Successfully');



      //refresh the list view
       $('#employee_list').listview("refresh");

        //update list view
         showCases();
         $.mobile.changePage('#home_page');

         //refresh the list view
      $('#employee_list').listview("refresh"); 
      return true;



});

          //Edit button
      $(".edit_button").live('click', 'tap', function(e){

e.stopPropagation();
$.mobile.changePage("#edit_employee_page");  // the edit_employee_page was brought to front for making 
                                        // the edit_employee_form inside the access scope

var employeeId=$(this).attr('id');          // here we are taking the id of the button for that particular employee.


 $('#edit_employee_page').ready(function(e) {       //this is for initializing the values on ready of the edit_employee_page
     for (var i = 0; i < employees.length; i++){
   if(employees[i].id == employeeId){
    document.forms["edit_employee_form"]["id"].value=employeeId;
    document.forms["edit_employee_form"]["employeeno"].value=employees[i].employeeno;
    document.forms["edit_employee_form"]["employeename"].value=employees[i].employeename;
    document.forms["edit_employee_form"]["employeebirth"].value=employees[i].employeebirth;
    document.forms["edit_employee_form"]["employeestate"].value=employees[i].employeestate;
    document.forms["edit_employee_form"]["employeephone"].value=employees[i].employeephone;
    document.forms["edit_employee_form"]["id"].setAttribute('id',"readonly");



   }
     }

});


    return false;
});
```

Here is the code for the dynamic list view, and dynamic pages for each list item

```
                          //add an eliment to list view
      var addEmployees = function(empData){
      //HTML content of one list element
      var listElementHTML = '<li><a class="employee_list" ui-btn ui-btn-e ui-btn-icon-right ui-icon-carat-r" data-transition="fade" data-split-icon="delete"  href="#item'+empData.id+'">'+empData.employeename+'<br> '+empData.birth+'</br></a></li>';


     //appending the HTML code to list view
      $('#employee_list').append(listElementHTML);


      //Dynamically adding HTML Pages
      var employeePageHTML = '<div id="item'+empData.id+'" data-role="page" data-theme="b"><div data-theme="a" data-role="header"><h1>'+empData.employeename+'</h1><a href="#home_page" data-icon="home" data-iconpos="left" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-btn ui-shadow ui-btn ui-btn-left ui-icon-home ui-btn-icon-notext ui-shadow ui-corner-all ui-btn-icon-left">Home</a>\
                          <a href="#delete'+empData.id+'" data-icon="delete" data-rel="dialog" class="ui-btn-middle delete_button">Delete</a></div><div data-role="content">\
                          <div data-role="collapsible" data-inset="false" data-collapsed="true" data-theme="b"><h3>Case Details</h3><i><strong>Employee No:</i></strong>'+empData.employeeno+'</br><i><p><strong>Employee Name:</i></strong> '+empData.employeename+'</br><i><p><strong>State Of Origine:</i></strong>'+empData.state+'</br><i><p><strong>Employee Phone:</i></strong>'+empData.employeephone+'</br><i><p><strong>Date Of Birth:</i></strong>'+empData.birth+'</div></div>\
                          <div data-position="fixed" data-theme="a" data-role="footer"><a href="#edit_employee_page" role="button" data-icon="edit" data-iconpos="" class="ui-btn  ui-icon-edit ui-btn-icon-right ui-btn-icon-notext ui-shadow ui-corner-all edit_button">Edit</a></div></div></div>';
```

Comment: hmm. addEventListener("storage", function(){$('#employee_list').listview("refresh");}, false); ?

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something but you're storing `employees` in local storage but it looks like you're editing `editEmployees`. I don't see where the edited information is copied back to the `employees` array.

Comment: @ Baldy, here is where I update database with the new data, "//After the selected case has been edited
localStorage.setItem("employees", JSON.stringify(employees));   //set the update values to localstorage
toast('Employee Updated Successfully');"

Answer (score 0):

You can make an AJAX request in jquery that loads the content asynchronously. Using AJAX allows requests and functions to act without reloading the browser because it connects to the server and back within the method. In your jquery you could do the following:

```
var data="all the data you want to update with";
$.ajax({

          $("body").load(data);
          //this would load that string inside the body but you can do whatever
            you want in this ajax function.

      });
```

Comment: I am using local storage and not a remote server, also the items are gotten from the form input filed, so I am confused how you mean I should add all data into the variable.

Comment: Okay. Although AJAX works conventionally with servers, it can also be used to simply load content without the browser reloading. My example of setting a variable and loading it to the body is just a general template of how to load data without refresh. You can load in however many variables using jquery load command. Look up documentation on the load command. It will show you its capability.